# SPO Modern Site: turn site title at page top into link (or turn it off)

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, title

Say my subsite is named "User EDU". The words "User EDU" appear at the top of every page, next to the site icon.

My customer would like to have those pages be a link back to the site home page. As of now it's just text.

If it can't be a link, can it be turned off? I could just make the site icon a graphic that says "User EDU" and solve the problem that way (since the icon links back to the home page).

Keep in mind that on a team site in my organization, I can't use scripting or CSS, or the Content Editor web part. I should also mention that I am not a SharePoint admin, just a site owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, then the words of site name only occur in the home page.  In other pages, it will display the page name beside the site icon.

It is by design.

We cannot hide the words of the site name in the home page by OOB method.

Comment: Thank you, Amy. So it's policy to make SharePoint sites unconfigurable and nonstandard? Frustrating, but you have answered my question. Appreciated.

Comment: yes, it is by design.